# Is there a material that can drain or lessen Force powers?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars canon, is there a material that can drain or lessen Force powers? For example, if a Force wielder was in a room built of this material, their Force powers would be lessened, so they would not be able (or would be severely less able) to perform Force powers such as Force pulls/pushes, lightning or chokes. In canon, is there a material like this?

Comment: Kryptonite. No, wait...

Comment: The only thing I know of that dampens the Force would be the lizard-like Ysalamiri (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ysalamir). I suppose one could build a room out of those...

Comment: are you looking for current (Disney) canon or old EU Legends?

Comment: If Disney canon - Ysalamiri as Force dampeners are a 'nope' at this time: https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/755402873324920834

Comment: Only in Legends, the material Universal energy cages were made of. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Universal_Energy_Cage

Comment: Gosh I just saw this question again and was about to rewrite the exact same comment.

Comment: A big stick can do it pretty well if it has enough momentum in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Obi-Wan in The Phantom Menace comes to mind when we was trapped behind forcefields during "Duel of the Fates". He looked fairly helpless while watching Qui-Gon and Maul go at it. If he had been able to use the Force to assist Qui-Gon I'm sure he would have--which it didn't seem like he was able to.

I'm not saying that forcefields or simple walls dampen a Force user's powers--I'm just saying that you might not need to go any further than that to effectively subdue them.

Obviously Ysalamiri are the best option available however as many have stated they are not Disney Canon. And I was serious about the Carbonite option.

Answer (score -2):

The follwing is from the EU:

The Ysalamiri are a lizard-like animal that dampen The Force, the Empire used cages to transport Jedis that they had captured.
There is also an ancient Jedi power which can be used to block Jedi powers.

Comment: Again this is asking specifically about canon and not the EU.